# Copy cell info with variable

Tags: excel, copy, cell, formula

I need to pull data from a cell on another sheet (Sheet1), using a variable on the Current sheet (Sheet2, 3, 4 etc)

..ie I have a formula that takes the current sheet name and returns a value in a cell (`A1` on current sheet),

I then need to go to a specific Column on another sheet but using the Row as derived from the sheet name something along the lines of:-

```
=Sheet1!H(Sheet2!A1)
```

where H is the column and (`Sheet2!A1`) is the row, and `A1` holds the value of the current sheet name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Excel INDIRECT function, it might do what you're looking for. It takes a string (which you can build) and used the value of the string to make a cell reference.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx